# Edit magazine to remove images

Tags: images, copyright

I made a David Bowie Magazine for school and want to present it on my homepage. I couldn't find any free-to-use images online, so I just took some from google images.

I thought about removing the pictures for the online-version and all the texts and replace them with a filler text but that doesn't work, e.g. on my cover I have a black/white picture with Bowies face. I can't replace it with just black.

How can I make my magazine legal for the internet? More specific: How should I edit my photos so that I can post my magazine on my website.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for public domain or Creative Commons images. [Wikipedia is a good Start](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bowie). If you attribute the works according to the license on the detail page of the Wikipedia image, then you should be on the safe side.

Here are some more references:

- [Wikimedia](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/David_Bowie)
- [Google images (Labelled for reuse)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=980&bih=620&ei=T-E-Wo2iCMb3UpSdjIgH&q=david%20bowie&oq=david%20bowie)
- [Flickr Creative Commons](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=David%20bowie&license=2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C9)

If I don’t know how to attribute an image, I use [tineye.com](http://tineye.com) to check where it comes from. Sometimes, you may find that public domain images actually belong to someone, so the only safe bet is to either make your own photos or to license the photos you want by directly contacting the photographer / rights holder. But generally speaking (as I am not a lawyer) as long as you do not make money with your usage, then it *probably* falls under the doctrine of fair use / more trouble than its worth.

If you want to be safe, you could offer to take down the offending image should there be a complaint in accordance with the DMCA.

Comment: Does that also work with celebrity pics? I already looked up wikipedia CC but back then I couldn't find good pictures there for my magazine.